# How to make Dojo a bit more lightweight?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've been looking at Dojo, and it has some nice tricks, however its quite huge IMHO. Basically when viewing my test my slow machine (600mhz), just loading Dojo was kind of painful, and can imagine lots of mobile devices will also not be happy with it.

Is there a slim version or something like that available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by 'loading Dojo'?
If you mean opening a page with a clean cache, and the site takes a long time to load, then it may be because you're using a non-minified version of the library.

If you mean loading some Dijits, or [a full-featured page](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=soria), then that's probably a combination of your browser's speed with JS, your computer's speed, and Dojo's speed.

Try loading something similar from another framework like [Ext JS](http://www.extjs.com) or [jQuery](http://ui.jquery.com) to see if they are any different.

Comment: Well compared to jQuery, Dojo is generally bigger. However the real issue was I WASN'T using the minified version. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6):

Dojo is not huge — it loads as much as you need to use while the base is 26k gzipped. And obviously for any real deployment:

- Use AOL or Google CDN. See [Dojo download page](http://dojotoolkit.org/downloads) for instructions.
- Build your very own streamlined version of Dojo. See [The Package System and Custom Builds](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-4-meta-dojo/package-system-and-custom-builds) for details.